# Python Classes and bounds

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

Trying to wrap my head around a piece of code i found for Scapy.

```
from scapy.utils import RawPcapReader
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP
        for pkt_data, pkt_metadata in RawPcapReader(file_name):

        ether_pkt = Ether(pkt_data)          
        if 'type' not in ether_pkt.fields:
            # LLC frames will have 'len' instead of 'type'.
            # We disregard those
            continue

        if ether_pkt.type != 0x0800:
            # disregard non-IPv4 packets
            continue

        ip_pkt = ether_pkt[IP]
```

The part which confuses me is my object ***ether_pkt*** is assigned to class ***Ether***
but something changes with ***ip_pkt = ether_pkt[IP]***

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One funny thing with python is that you can [bind all operators to do custom things](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). For instance, you can create an object where the `+` operator does something completely different.

In scapy, the bracket operator was implemented to mean "get the following layer" from the packet. Here you are dissecting a packet by specifying the first layer: Ethernet. This will dissect also dissect all the sub-layers, among which IP.

```
pkt = Ether()/IP()
pkt[IP] # Only the IP layer
d = bytes(pkt)  # The full packet as bytes
Ether(d)[IP]  # Dissect the packet, get the IP layer
```

More infos over https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html